# What is the selector naming convention for apps in `/apps` in the Angular Workspace?

Tags: angular, naming-conventions

I have about 10 apps in the `/apps` folder.

Should the selector of the `@Component`s be prefixed with `app-`?

e.g. `app-root`,

or should it be all prefixed with the app name?

E.g. if one of my apps is called `FooBar`, then I will have a component called `fb-root`? And another project one is called `HelloWorld`, then I will have a component called `hw-root`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prefix helps prevent name collisions between component libraries. You can give it any prefix you want, but I would first check if the prefix is already used by any libraries you might want to use in the future.

"mat" is used by the Angular Material as an example, and "ngx" is used by the Bootstrap library and there are many others.

It's an unofficial standard that "app" is a reserved prefix used by applications, and it ensures there won't be two components trying to use the same selector.

In your example, you say "FooBar" would have the prefix "fb", but that is likely to be the same prefix used by a Facebook component library.

Also the prefix "ng" was a popular prefix used by many open source libraries when Angular 2 was first released. It's popularity as a prefix continues today, and I wouldn't recommend using it.

So "app" is safe and anything else is basically upto you.

Comment: How do you check your selector name with all libraries?

Answer (score 4):

I would rather choose the second one `fb-root` because it shows from which application this component is. Also if you have applications not only in `/apps` folder, or you have libraries as well, you can combine prefixes like `app-fb-root`. But again if you don't, it's better to use just `fb-root`.